# Windows Phone 7 IsolatedStorage when sideloading

Tags: windows-phone-7, sideloading

Is there a way when I am testing my own app (sideloaded to my phone), that I can treat my version as an update to my original application.

Lets say I'm going from 1.5 to 1.6 of my app.  I want to use the exact same IsololatedStorage data that is in 1.5 with my new version (for testing).  Is there a way to do this?
In the past it just creates a new instance of my application and I would have 1.5 and 1.6 on my phone.

Anyway of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you sideloading for testing? Deploying via VS/Blend or using the [CoreCon API](http://justinangel.net/WindowsPhone7NeuronsApp#BlogPost=WindowsPhone7EmulatorAutomation)?

If using VS/Blend - you'll have to manipulate the contents of IsolatedStorage in code/debug.

If using CoreCon you can just upload the old version of the files to IsolatedStorage.

Comment: Man that is one heck of a tutorial...  I guess the quick and easy answer is no...  However the CoreCon API appeared to have a way (with some extra work).  Thanks for sharing that.  I'll check that out.